# converting from dataframe to list introduces factors

Tags: r, list

I have a dataframe which i need to convert from, df:

```
group      ID
1     23143
1      7273
1      5578
3     10982
2      9722
3     26994
2      6497
..     ...
```

to a list like:

```
$C1
 [1] "23143" "7273" "5578"
$C2
 [1] "9722" "6497"
$C3
 [1] "10982" "26994"
```

I can do this by:

```
list <- split.data.frame(df,df$group)
list <-lapply(ss,"[[","ID)
```

but this introduces factors for the ID values, how can i convert this list into characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by running your code with `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` to prevent strings from being automatically turned into factors. With that said, the example data you gave doesn't result in strings anyway, so I'm not sure if maybe your actual data is different.

Your data:

```
df <- data.frame(group=c(1,1,1,3,2,3,2),
                 ID=c(23143,7273,5587,10982,9722,26994,6497))

newlist <- split.data.frame(df,df$group)
newlist <-lapply(newlist,`[[`,"ID")

class(newlist[[1]])

[1] "numeric"
```

Some string data:

```
df2 <- data.frame(group=c(1,1,1,3,2,3,2),
                 ID=c("Joe","Sam","Rod","Mike","Steny","Larry","Chris"))

newlist2 <- split.data.frame(df2,df2$group)
newlist2 <-lapply(newlist2,`[[`,"ID")

class(newlist2[[1]])

[1] "factor"
```

With options set:

```
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df3 <- data.frame(group=c(1,1,1,3,2,3,2),
                  ID=c("Joe","Sam","Rod","Mike","Steny","Larry","Chris"))

newlist3<- split.data.frame(df3,df3$group)
newlist3 <-lapply(newlist3,`[[`,"ID")

class(newlist3[[1]])

[1] "character"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
with(df, split(ID, group))
```

although you have some type of type issue going on, presumably.  If you want your output to be character, you can try:

```
with(df, split(ID, as.character(group)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `split` is introducing the factors. They must be in the original `df` data.frame. If you look at `str(df)` are they factors there? If so, how are you creating that table? From `read.table`? Because normally R doesn't automatically convert values that are clearly numeric to factors unless there it at least one non-numeric value in the column.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `colClasses = 'numeric'` if you're reading from file with `read.table` or others.  Otherwise, `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, as everyone has mentioned already.

```
> df <- data.frame(group=c(1,1,1,3,2,3,2),
                   ID=c(23143,7273,5587,10982,9722,26994,6497))
> s <- split(df$ID, df$group)
> names(s) <- paste0("C", seq(s))
> s
# $C1
# [1] 23143  7273  5587

# $C2
# [1] 9722 6497

# $C3
# [1] 10982 26994

> sapply(s, class)
       C1        C2        C3 
"numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```